My data will be used in a patent application – what can I ask for?
I am a postdoc. A lab we collaborate with invented something, and they will try to patent this invention. They did all of the work so far, in vitro & in cells, to develop the invention, and now it is my turn to test this invention in vivo (in an animal model). So it is not my invention, but my data (if the experiments are successful) will be in the patent.
What is my best strategy to try to benefit from this patent application? What can I reasonably ask for?
I work in France. My contract is clear that I do not own the IP of an invention I make during the project, but it also says that the university will put my name as inventor or co-inventor in case there is a patent application. Is this 'co-inventor' title a reasonable thing to ask for? Is this the best I can try? What does it entail?

You get to put a patent on your CV. That really is about it unless the patent actually gets licensed (most don’t) and then you might get some small amount of royalties.

Why not use this as a great learning opportunity by sitting down with your institution’s office of patents? You’re a postdoc, there to research and learn.

Since this is primarily driven by another lab, you should ask this questions to your own university - they should have a patent office that is very much interested in getting your university (and yourself as motivation) properly recognised in the process.

I had a colleague who contributed (greatly) to a patent filed by IBM when he held a research position there. He got a plaque for his wall.
But he also got an important entry in his CV that made advancement and future employment more likely.
I don't recall that he got more money from that, specifically, but that sort of thing contributes positively in any salary negotiation. And increased recognition in the field is a valuable thing.
Most(? many anyway) patents that are filed based on the works of academics and employed researchers are filed by the organizations and such is usually required by contract. While this may seem like a bad thing, the institution takes financial responsibility (not small) for filing and supporting the patent and, (even less small) for defending it if it is challenged. Few academics have the resources to deal with that, both time and money. The "compromise" may not be ideal, but it is pretty typical.
Your particular case is a bit different. The intellectual contributions seem to be almost entirely with others. You suggest that you are working under the direction of those who can more obviously claim to be creators/inventors.

Thanks. Your last paragraph is correct. Looking at definitions of "co-inventor" online, I think I could fit the bill though.

It depends on the nature of the contribution. I ran critical experiments which led to several patents during my postdoc. However, the intellectual contribution was predetermined before I was involved, I merely ran experiments, as told,, to validate it. I was left off the application. I would caution the OP to speak to the collaborators heading this project to see if they intend to include them on the patent. If the patent is a result of a discovery from their measurements, that is a strong argument. If their experiments are just technical work to validate the idea, then it can go either way.
